# php add class to Link in UL LI of current page

Tags: php, html, regex

trying with regex at php to add a "curPage" class to my ul-li menu before sending to browser.
code:

```
$loadedMenu=preg_replace("/a href=\"" . $file . ".htm\"/", "a href=\"" . $file . ".htm\" class=\"curPage\"", $loadedMenu);
```

content of $loadedMenu:

```
<nav><ul><li rel="file" id="516054b57fbba"><a href="index.htm">דף הבית</a></li><li rel="file" id="51681f81a440b"><a href="newuser.htm">משתמש חדש</a></li><li rel="file" id="516054b57fb40"><a href="about.htm">אודות</a></li><li rel="file" id="5160f37b822a3"><a href="%D7%93%D7%A3%20%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9.htm">דף חדש</a></li><li rel="folder" id="516054d162176"><a href="#" style="cursor:text;">תיקייה חדשה</a><ul><li rel="file" id="516054b57fc62"><a href="%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%98%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99.htm">מיטל הנסיכה שלי</a></li><li rel="file" id="516054b57fc9a"><a href="%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F.htm">נסיון</a></li><li rel="file" id="516054b57fb82"><a href="help.htm">עזרה</a></li></ul></li><li rel="folfil" id="5160552162177"><a href="%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9F.htm">תיקיית תוכן</a><ul><li rel="file" id="516054b57fbf2"><a href="test.htm">test</a></li></ul></li><li rel="file" id="516054b57fc2a"><a href="%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94.htm">גלידה</a></li><li rel="file" id="516054b57fcd2"><a href="%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F0.htm">נסיון0</a></li></ul></nav>
```

Comment: It fails with an error or what?

Comment: You probably should be using str_replace rather than preg_replace. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @starshine531 is the str_replace works just as fast and efficient as the preg_replace?

Comment: str_replace is faster than preg_replace.  You only need preg_replace when your matching string is less specific.  Given that you're setting the search to a very specific string, there's no need to match a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is so much error prone to parse HTML text like you're doing that it is almost no-no.**

Better to use [DOM parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse and modify HTML like this code:

```
$file = 'foo.htm'; // set your value here
# fetch your HTML content here
$html = <<< EOF
<html>
<a href="http://example.com/foo.htm">Click link1</a> morestuff
<a href="http://www.example.com/foo/baz">Click www.example.com</a> morestuff
<a href="http://notexample.com/foo/bar">notexample.com</a> morestuff
<a href="http://example.com/foo.htm">Click link1</a>
</html>
EOF;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// find all hrefs with $file in it
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href, '" . $file . "')]");
// iterate thru found links
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    # add class attribute to them
    $node->setAttribute('class', 'curPage');
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><a href="http://example.com/foo.htm" class="curPage">Click link1</a> morestuff
<a href="http://www.example.com/foo/baz">Click www.example.com</a> morestuff
<a href="http://notexample.com/foo/bar">notexample.com</a> morestuff
<a href="http://example.com/foo.htm" class="curPage">Click link1</a>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the awsome code, though my code only parse a part of code ul-li only and the this isn't prone to errors because the text inserted to the ul-li before saving is filtered, the ul li is being made with a DOM parser but adding a dom parser for adding this class will slow it down too much, see this code going to be ran 1-3 times every php file ran on the server, it must be dont fast and regex is the answare here, but thank you very much! i'm upvoting this and changing the title so people can use this answare but still i need the regex fixed.

Comment: Thanks for kind words. I suggest you post content of `$loadedMenu` variable to explain your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Executing this code on the command line works fine. That part that does not work is hidden from us.

```
<?php

$file = "index";
$loadedMenu = '<a href="'.$file.'.htm">whatever</a>';

$loadedMenu=preg_replace("/a href=\"" . $file . ".htm\"/", "a href=\"" . $file . ".htm\" class=\"curPage\"", $loadedMenu);

echo $loadedMenu;
// <a href="index.htm" class="curPage">whatever</a>

?>
```

Perhaps the initial value of `loadedMenu` has single quotes instead of double, or a slightly different href value.

You could use a slightly more generic regex, capturing any filename instead of the specific file in your code...

```
$loadedMenu=preg_replace('/a href="(.+?)"/', 'a href="$1" class="curPage"', $loadedMenu);
```

Comment: i Edited to include the code, from some reason it fails, and i cant even get the error_log due to a fail cheap web server host :(